# What is the white paneling under the vinyl on my house, and how can I fix it?

Tags: exterior

On the back of my house, the section between the vinyl siding and the ground is covered with some sort of white, textured material. What exactly is it? Is it stucco?[image: Bottom of house]

Secondly, what would be the best way to fix that gash in it that came from trimming along there with a string trimmer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that someone put a gash in it with a string trimmer, its likely stucco over rigid foam insulation panels.

If there's wire mesh in there as well, it's likely a traditional multi-coat stucco finish that can be repaired using stucco repair techniques.

If there's no wire mesh, you may have an EIFS wall (exterior insulation finishing system), which is kind of insulation and finish in one. This should be repaired using products and techniques specific to EIFS.